# Elisp: defmacro with &body and &rest behave differently?

Tags: elisp, elisp-macro

I thought `&body` and `&rest` were supposed to behave the same, so this puzzled me:

```
ELISP> (defmacro mrest (&rest rest))                                                                                                                                                                                              
mrest                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ELISP> (mrest)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
nil                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ELISP> (mrest 1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
nil                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ELISP> (mrest 1 2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
nil                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ELISP> (mrest 1 2 3)                                                                                                                                                                                                              
nil                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ELISP> (mrest 1 2 3 4)                                                                                                                                                                                                            
nil                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ELISP> (defmacro mbody (&body body))                                                                                                                                                                                              
mbody                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ELISP> (mbody)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
*** Eval error ***  Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (&body body) nil), 0                                                                                                                                                       
ELISP> (mbody 1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
*** Eval error ***  Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (&body body) nil), 1                                                                                                                                                       
ELISP> (mbody 1 2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
nil                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ELISP> (mbody 1 2 3)                                                                                                                                                                                                              
*** Eval error ***  Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (&body body) nil), 3                                                                                                                                                       
ELISP> (mbody 1 2 3 4)                                                                                                                                                                                                            
*** Eval error ***  Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (&body body) nil), 4
```

Why does elisp insist on `mbody` having exactly two arguments here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Emacs Lisp `defmacro` doesn't support `&body` at all.  Therefore in your example, `&body` is the name of one of two mandatory arguments.

You want the `cl-lib` variant, `cl-defmacro`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just defined two inputs for the macro, `&body` and `body` since they are both valid symbols names, so it's logic to ask for two arguments.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Type.html